# Best practice for pushing the results of a HTTP operation into a ReplaySubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a requirement in my Angular 4 app to fetch some data from an HTTP request, do some processing on that data and push the result into a `ReplaySubject`. I am mocking up some pagination code on the client-side because the API isn't quite ready yet.

The pattern I am using is this:

```
private searchResultsSource = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
public searchResults$ = this.searchResultsSource.asObservable();

// ...

protected loadResults() {
  this.apiService
      .get( 'some_url/' ) // this returns a JSON string
      .map( ( results ) => {
        return {
          results: _.chain( results )
                    .drop( this.pageSize * (this.page - 1) )
                    .take( this.pageSize )
                    .value(),
          totalResultsCounts: results.length,
          isLastPage: this.pageSize * this.page >= results.length
        };
      } )
      .subscribe((page) => this.searchResultsSource.next(page));
}
```

This seems a little smelly to me. Calling `next()` within a `subscribe()` seems like a dodgy pattern. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, you are subscribing the value from you apiService call, and then you insert the value to your subject using `next`. I think that's the correct way to handle it.. Please tag me if someone gives a good explanation about this.. :)

Comment: If your requirement is really to push some data into a subject, then you would have to call `next` on the subject somewhere. And the best place for that would be where you observe the data, i.e. `subscribe()`. Also bear in mind that `subscribe` can also take an `Observer` object and your subject is in fact an `Observer` itself, so you can just pass it directly without calling `next` explicitly: `.subscribe(this.searchResultsSource)`.

Comment: I think this depends on what you want to do with `searchResultsSource` later. Are the multiple services that need to call `next` on it? If so then you're probably doing it right already. There's also the `multicast` operator that you might use instead of the next `callback` you don't like but this really depends on your usecase. Also, you probably don't want to be using `.subscribe(this.searchResultsSource)` because Subjects have internal state https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/9518/subject/29424/subject-and-its-internal-state#t=201707310621210883553

Comment: @martin is absolutely right: don't pass the subject to `subscribe` unless you want it to receive also `error` and `complete` notifications from the source.